# SQL Server Graph Tables - navigate through certain nodes to find end

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, sql-graph, sql-server-graph, graph-table

I have a structure of graph tables containing 2 Node tables and 1 Edge table.

**Symptom** table is a Node table and **Syndrome_Causes** is an Edge table. Also, there is another Node table called **Syndrome**.

My goal is to have a query where I can traverse my graph, going through specific nodes.

I have written the below query to show you all possible routes, starting from the "Cardiovascular" node, but I would need to filter out the results going through the path, underlined with red in the following image (*Cardiovascular->Palpitations->Duration->Interval->Days*).

```
select distinct
    s1.symptom_name
    , string_agg(s2.symptom_name, '->') within group (graph path) AS links
    , last_value(s2.symptom_name) within group (graph path) as last_match
from symptom as s1,
    syndrome_causes for path as sc1,
    symptom         for path as s2
where match(
    shortest_path(s1(-(sc1)->s2)+)
    )
    and s1.symptom_name = 'Cardiovascular'
```

[image]

I have thought about adding another filtering condition to the `WHERE` clause, but I can't figure out how I could write it so that I constrain the node to go only through the values in the **"links"** column.

Mind you, I know and I can pass it the value in the **links** column to filter the rows and get me to the "Days" value in **`last_match`** column, but my intention is to filter it by following a certain path through nodes (a verification), something like below:

```
where match(
    shortest_path(s1(-(sc1)->s2)+)
    )
    and s1.symptom_name = 'Cardiovascular'
    and s2.symptom_name = ALL('Palpitations, 'Duration', 'Interval', 'Days')
```

However, this gives out an error:

> The alias or identifier 's2.symptom_name' cannot be used in the select
> list, order by, group by, or having context.

**So, is there a way to constrain a path search to go through certain nodes?**

Answer (score 1):

> So, is there a way to constrain a path search to go through certain
> nodes?

It is possible to filter/limit the nodes to be considered for the path, by selecting only specific values "for path", but this does not dictate how the path is traversed.

```
......
from symptom as s1,
syndrome_causes for path as sc1,
(select * from symptom where symptom_name in ('Palpitations', 'Duration', 'Interval', 'Days')) for path as s2
......
```

Comment: for filtering on the last_match and/or path/[links], derive the whole query: `select * from (select distinct...........and s1.symptom_name = 'Cardiovascular') as drv where drv.last_match = 'Days' and drv.links=concat('Palpilations', '->', 'Duration',.......'Days')`